# how to open all the files in the system using file filter driver?

Tags: wdk

I am trying to implementing malware analysis using file filter driver in windows.
I need to open all the file in the system to check for the hex values of the malware. but i can't open all the files in the system.what should i do to open the files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You sort of need to know a bit about the Native API before moving to kernel-mode software development. I suggest you take a huge step back and go back to user-mode with the Win32 API because clearly you don't know what you are doing and all you are going to do is develop something that will harm your own or someone else's environment.

You need to enumerate the files in directories and make it recursive, this can be achieved with ZwQueryDirectoryFile however. The enumeration is a start.

Move down to user-mode because kernel-mode isn't a place for messing around in. You should at-least know the basics before trying to make a malware analysis system.